# Recursive deferred Filesystem search for images

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, recursion, deferred

I'm trying to loop through android file system to look for any images. I wrote the below recursive method, however its not working. I tried to use the same defer through out the recursion but I'm unable to find a condition which can recognize that its end of recursion and return the results.

```
 getEntries: function(path, def, deepCount, results) {
        var self = this;
        var deferred = def || $q.defer();
        var deepCount = deepCount || 0;
        var results = results || [];
        // $cordovaDialogs.alert("inside entries");
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(fileSystem) {
            var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var arrayLength = entries.length;

                // var log = [];
                // angular.forEach(entries, function(value, key) {
                //   if(key.isDirectory )
                // });
              //  $cordovaDialogs.alert("got entries");
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    var file = entries[i];
                   // $cordovaDialogs.alert(file);                   
                    if(file.isDirectory){
                        deepCount += 1;
                        self.getEntries(file.nativeURL, deferred, deepCount, results);                            
                    }
                    else if (file.isFile){
                        //check if the file extension is of type image
                        if(file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)){
                            results.push(file.nativeURL);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!def && deepCount == 1 ) { 
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                }
                else {
                    deepCount -= 1;
                }
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
               console.log(error);
            });
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
            console.log(error);

        });

       //return results;
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the solution given in the question- [How to iterate through file system directories and files using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234933/how-to-iterate-through-file-system-directories-and-files-using-javascript)

However, I noticed that problem with my approach was, I was calling window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL in the recursive call, which was causing the problem. I should be just looping through the directories.